# os.path.isfile faster than glob.glob?

Tags: python-2.7

I took a look at the source codes. `glob.glob` uses `os.listdir` and `fnmatch` to filter the file path. `os.path.isfile` tries to get file stat. However, I didn't find the source code for `os.listdir` and don't know how it's implemented.

When checking if a file exists, is `os.path.isfile` much faster than `glob.glob` since `os.listdir` takes time to list all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob('./')` essentially does what `ls *` would do on the command line. `os.path.isfile` needs a specific file handle in order to work, this means it will usually be faster than glob, simply because there will be less operations and glob does not return a boolean value. Here is a sample timed in my working directory

with glob:

```
In [2]: %timeit glob.glob('./')

The slowest run took 15.81 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached

100000 loops, best of 3: 9.8 μs per loop
```

with listdir:

```
In [5]: %timeit os.path.isfile('./')

The slowest run took 24.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached

100000 loops, best of 3: 4.04 μs per loop
```